# How to fix upgrade to SonarQube 5?

Tags: sonarqube

The upgrade from SonarQube 4.0 to 5.0.1 fails during the database upgrade. I followed [these instructions](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading), but the setup does not complete:

```
    ### Error updating database.  Cause:         java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SONAR.RULES_REPO_KEY) violated

    ### The error may involve org.sonar.core.rule.RuleMapper.insert-Inline
    ### The error occurred while setting parameters
    ### SQL: insert into rules           (plugin_rule_key, plugin_name,         description, description_format, status, name, plugin_config_key, priority,     is_template, language, template_id,     characteristic_id, default_characteristic_id, remediation_function, default_remediation_function,     remediation_coeff, default_remediation_coeff, remediation_offset, default_remediation_offset,     effort_to_fix_description, tags, system_tags, note_data, note_user_login, note_created_at, note_updated_at,     created_at, updated_at)         values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,     ?, ?, ?, ?,     ?, ?, ?, ?,     ?, ?, ?, ?,     ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,     ?, ?, ?)
    ### Cause: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SONAR.RULES_REPO_KEY) violated
    org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:26)
    org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:154)
    org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:141)
    org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:51)
    org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.insert(Unknown Source)
    org.sonar.server.rule.db.RuleDao.doInsert(RuleDao.java:58)
    org.sonar.server.rule.db.RuleDao.doInsert(RuleDao.java:36)
    org.sonar.server.db.BaseDao.insert(BaseDao.java:243)
    org.sonar.server.db.BaseDao.insert(BaseDao.java:218)
    org.sonar.server.rule.RegisterRules.createRuleDto(RegisterRules.java:224)
    org.sonar.server.rule.RegisterRules.registerRule(RegisterRules.java:130)
    org.sonar.server.rule.RegisterRules.start(RegisterRules.java:106)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
    org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
    org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
    org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
    org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
    org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015)
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008)
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
    org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents$1.doPrivileged(ServerComponents.java:665)
    org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:43)
    org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents.executeStartupTasks(ServerComponents.java:661)
    org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:126)
    org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel34Containers(Platform.java:122)
    org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:81)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:440)
    org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:304)
    org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:52)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
    org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:336)
    org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.call(BlockBody.java:73)
    org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)
    org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290)
    org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:228)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:97)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I hope I upgraded the plugins correctly: **edit: ... but I didn't.**

```
    -rwx------+ 1 pwillems       Domain Users 1366553 Nov 12  2012 CSharpPluginsEcosystem-1.4.zip
    -rwx------+ 1 pwillems       Domain Users     105 Mar  5 13:53 README.txt
    drwx------+ 1 Administrators Domain Users       0 Mar  6 12:41 findbugs-2.0.1
    -rwx------+ 1 pwillems       Domain Users   29436 Jul 12  2012 findbugs-ant.jar
    drwx------+ 1 pwillems       Domain Users       0 Mar 10 12:58 not for 4.0
    drwx------+ 1 pwillems       Domain Users       0 Mar  6 16:16 obsolete Java 2.4
    -rwx------+ 1 pwillems       Domain Users    9205 Mar  5 12:21 sonar-branding-plugin-1.0.jar
    -rwx------+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 2014901 Mar  6 11:19 sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.2.jar
    -rwx------+ 1 Administrators Domain Users   10325 Mar  6 11:34 sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.6.3.jar
    -rwx------+ 1 pwillems       Domain Users  917316 Mar  6 09:42 sonar-csharp-plugin-3.3.jar
    -rwx------+ 1 pwillems       Domain Users    7247 Nov 28  2012 sonar-csv-export-plugin-1.3.jar
    -rwx------+ 1 pwillems       Domain Users  102668 Nov 18  2013 sonar-dotnet-fxcop-plugin-2.1.jar
    -rwx------+ 1 pwillems       Domain Users   84620 Nov 18  2013 sonar-dotnet-gallio-plugin-2.1.jar
    -rwx------+ 1 pwillems       Domain Users  624800 Nov 18  2013 sonar-dotnet-gendarme-plugin-2.1.jar
    -rwx------+ 1 pwillems       Domain Users  280291 Nov 18  2013 sonar-dotnet-ndeps-plugin-2.1.jar
    -rwx------+ 1 pwillems       Domain Users   59047 Nov 18  2013 sonar-dotnet-plugin-2.1.jar
    -rwx------+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 1012812 Mar  6 11:37 sonar-issues-report-plugin-1.3.jar
    -rwx------+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 2468589 Mar  6 11:04 sonar-java-plugin-3.0.jar
    -rwx------+ 1 pwillems       Domain Users   30646 Feb  4  2014 sonar-ldap-plugin-1.4.jar
    -rwx------+ 1 pwillems       Domain Users  857763 Sep 16 13:08 sonar-plsql-plugin-2.6.jar
    -rwx------+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 3568440 Mar  6 11:20 sonar-pmd-plugin-2.3.jar
    drwx------+ 1 Administrators Domain Users       0 Mar  6 12:41 sonar-runner-2.0
    -rwx------+ 1 pwillems       Domain Users   36019 Mar  6 09:42 sonar-stylecop-plugin-1.1.jar
    -rwx------+ 1 pwillems       Domain Users   26259 Mar  6 09:42 sonar-visual-studio-plugin-1.2.jar
```

This is the recent history in the sonar.log:

```
    2015.03.10 13:14:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer]  Index source files
    2015.03.10 13:15:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer]  204829 requests processed
    2015.03.10 13:16:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer]  488960 requests processed
    2015.03.10 13:17:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer]  769172 requests processed
    2015.03.10 13:18:41 INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer]  1009002 requests processed
    2015.03.10 13:19:41 INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer]  1302412 requests processed
    2015.03.10 13:20:41 INFO  web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer]  1608777 requests processed
    2015.03.10 13:21:21 INFO  web[o.s.a.u.TimeProfiler]  Load metrics...
    2015.03.10 13:21:22 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics]  Cleaning quality gate conditions
    2015.03.10 13:21:22 INFO  web[o.s.a.u.TimeProfiler]  Load metrics done: 953 ms
    2015.03.10 13:21:22 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDebtModel]  Register technical debt model...
    2015.03.10 13:21:22 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDebtModel]  Register technical debt model done: 78 ms
    2015.03.10 13:21:22 INFO  web[o.s.a.u.TimeProfiler]  Register rules...
    2015.03.10 13:21:35 INFO  web[o.s.a.u.TimeProfiler]  Register rules done: 12985 ms
    2015.03.10 13:21:35 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]  Fail to upgrade database
```

What would be useful to investigate or try? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The sonar-dotnet-*-plugins break the upgrade. They are obsolete (see [outdated C# Ecosystem](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Upgrade+from+the+.NET+ecosystem+version+2.1)) and must be removed.

Figured this out when I noticed that these plugins failed the "migration" of an empty database.